# htaccess - unwanted redirection to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
RewriteEngine ON

# example.com/index.php?c=kb -> example.com/kb
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the above works fine, now I want internally `example.com/contact` to be rewritten into `example.com/contact.php`  where I tried:

```
# contact -> contact.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php? [L]
```

problem - this redirects me to `index.php` if I remove the first block of code (about index.php) - the second part works fine - there is no redirection to index.php, seems something is wrong with the second `RewriteCond`.

Comment: _"what is the reason"_ - the _order_ in which you are trying to do those things, maybe?

Comment: @CBroe - how to rewrite the second Condition and keep the above order ?

Comment: Why in that order? That makes little sense. You should always go from most to least specific. You would have to explicitly add an exception to your first block, that lets requests for `/contact` pass through unchanged, if you really wanted to keep this order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for contact.php rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]

# example.com/index.php?c=kb -> example.com/kb
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php/?\?c=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

##For internal rewrite rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

***OR*** in case you have to internally rewrite to about to about.php OR contact to contact.php then you can use following rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for contact.php rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(contact|about)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]

# example.com/index.php?c=kb -> example.com/kb
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php/?\?c=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

##For internal rewrite rules here.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it works Thanks a lot Especially for `contact|about` part

Comment: Nice answer ++ bro